# Solicitudes duplicadas al generar respuestas por OpenAI y enviarlas a Whatsapp Api Cloud

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-webhook

Tengo un problema con la api de whatsapp api cloud, es un problema de esos que te dan dolor de cabeza y que ni siquiera sabes como resumirlo para solicitar ayuda y como sobre todo como pedirla para no enredar a quien te lea porque ni tu mismo sabes que pasa

Bueno para darles un poco de contexto: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Nodejs, Express y Typescript. Mi aplicación es pequeña y lo que hace es conectarse al webhook de whatsapp api cloud, para poder recibir mensajes desde whatsapp a mi servidor y generar acciones de respuesta dependiendo de los mensajes recibidos. Estoy simulando un bot con ayuda de openAI, yo recibo la pregunta del usuario a traves del webhook, reviso si es texto, si es asi, la proceso para enviarla a la api de OpenAI, obtengo una respuesta de esta y esa respuesta se la envio a Whatsapp a traves de una peticion autorizada a la api graph de Meta.

Es un flujo bastante sencillo, pero las cosas empezaron a complicarse cuando empecé a notar que las respuesta las duplicaba. Es decir, el usuario enviaba una pregunta y el bot la contestaba mas de una vez. Busque practicas de programacion, re estructure mi codigo pero nada me llevo a una solucion. Esto es lo que hago actualmente

1.- Cree un array de conversaciones que me ayude a controlar si las respuestas se duplican en la conversación. Cuando llegue una pregunta de un usuario, primero se debe verificar si ese usuario ya tiene una conversación abierta. Si es así, se busca la respuesta si ya se le ha enviado, y si es así, no envías la respuesta de nuevo. Si el usuario no tiene una conversación abierta, creas una nueva entrada en el objeto para ese usuario y envías la respuesta.

2.- Antes de enviar cualquier respuesta enviar el mensaje "Escribiendo..." para que el usuario sepa que el bot está escribiendo su respuesta, es importante validar que el mensaje “Escribiendo..." solo se debe enviar cuando se conteste la conversación del usuario, si encuentra una conversación creado entonces que NO lo envié

3.- Si la petición a OpenAI se está tardando más de 10 segundos en resolverse antes de resolverse enviarle al usuario "No me he olvidado de ti, estoy pensando tu respuesta" para no desesperar al usuario y ofrecerle una buena experiencia

4.- Cree una bandera para verificar si hay varias conversaciones abiertas y de esa forma no contestarle a la siguiente conversación si no se ha resuelto la primera que se creó y mientras se resuelve enviar el mensaje "Pensando..." al usuario

5.- Si el mensaje de texto que genero openAI sobrepasa cierto limite de caracteres lo envio separada para asegurarme que si whatsapp no pudo procesar el texto porque es muy grande lo envie por partes

Como ven, son diferentes estrategias para poder administrar las conversaciones y asi evitar la duplicidad.

Cabe destacar que es una aplicacion de pruebas y no esta en un ambiente de produccion asi que no me tengo que preocupar por recibir grandes cantidades de solicitudes, solo que me tiene muy confundida que hace que se duplique.

Porque cuando hago pruebas en postman el flujo va bien, pero cuando ya subo a mi servidor empieza la duplicidad en las respuestas, la api esta dockerizada con ubunto, pero bueno no creo que sea eso. No se mucho de servidores realmente y menos de docker, el servidor es un windows server configurado con IIS y docker corre la aplicación, no se si por alli va el asunto, pero no le encuentro sentido, si alguien sabe porfavor hagamelo saber para ver por donde es que se duplican las respuestas. Además que noto que solo pasa cuando los caracteres que envia whatsapp son demasiado grandes

Necesito ayuda, si alguien aqui es experto en estructuras de trafico, procesamiento asincrono en nodejs, desenvolmiento de hilos en nodejs o algo con ese tema, porque de verdad estaria muy agradecida si alguien con conocimiento de estructura de datos me ayuda a entender porque me sucede esto, que estoy haciendo mal en mi codigo. Se que es complicado solo analizar codigo, pero he buscado en internet y pienso que puede ser la forma en que desenvuelvo el codigo, tal vez no estoy administrando correctamente mi estructura de datos

Perdon si sueno muy desesperada, pero es que ya tengo tres semanas con esto y no me explico porque y en las comunidades de desarrollo de ambos servicios no he obtenido respuesta, ademas de que el lenguaje es un limite para mi. Creo que resumi bien mi problema, si falta algo haganmelo saber, no hago un demo por tema de keys

```
    import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
    import { ID_CELL, TOKEN_CLOUD_API_WSP, VERIFICATION_TOKEN } from "../utils/secrets";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { getAnswerFromOpenAI } from "../services/chatgptServices";
    
    interface Conversation {
        from: string,
        question: string,
        answer: string,
        isBot: {
            typing: boolean;
            thinking: boolean;
        };
    }
    
    let conversations: Conversation[] = [];
    let isProcessing = false;
    
    export const verifyToken = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
    
            let accessToken = VERIFICATION_TOKEN;
    
            if (req.query['hub.mode'] === 'subscribe' && req.query['hub.verify_token'] === accessToken) {
                res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(400);
            }
    
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
    
    export const receiveMessage = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        try {
            let entry = (req.body["entry"])[0];
            let changes = (entry["changes"])[0];
            let value = changes["value"];
            let messageObject = value["messages"];
            let isBotTyping: boolean = false;
            let isBotThinking: boolean = false;
    
            if (typeof messageObject !== "undefined") {
    
                let messages = messageObject[0];
                let phoneNumber = messages["from"];
                let typeMessage = messages["type"];
    
                if (typeMessage === "text") {
    
                    const question = (messages["text"])["body"];
    
                    console.log(`Question sent from ${phoneNumber}: ${question}`);
    
                    let conversation = conversations.find((message) => message.question === question && message.from === phoneNumber);
    
                    if (conversation) {
                        console.log("Ya existe conversacion");
                        res.status(200);
                    } else {
    
                        await sendMessageToWhatsApp(phoneNumber, "Escribiendo...");
                        isBotTyping = true;
    
                        const delay = 10000; // 10 segundos
                        const timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
                            const messageWait = 'No me he olvidado de ti, solo estoy pensando tu respuesta.';
                            console.log(messageWait);
                            await sendMessageToWhatsApp(phoneNumber, messageWait);
                        }, delay);
    
                        if (isProcessing) {
                            console.log('Estoy procesando otra solicitud. Por favor, espera unos minutos y vuelve a intentarlo.');
                            await sendMessageToWhatsApp(phoneNumber, "Pensando...");
                            isBotThinking = true;
                            return res.status(201);
                        }
                        isProcessing = true;
    
                        const responseOpenAI = await getAnswerFromOpenAI(question);
    
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
    
                        const maxLongitud = 500;
                        const answer = responseOpenAI?.data.choices[0].message.content.trim() ?? "Ops, Lo siento! No puedo responderte actualmente, intentalo más tarde.";
    
                        if (answer.length <= maxLongitud) {
                            await sendMessageToWhatsApp(phoneNumber, answer);
                        } else {
                            const chunks = answer.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${maxLongitud}}`, 'g'));
                            const promises = chunks.map((chunk) => sendMessageToWhatsApp(phoneNumber, chunk));
                            await Promise.all(promises);
                        }
                        
                        const newConversation = {
                            from: phoneNumber,
                            question,
                            answer,
                            isBot: {
                                typing: isBotTyping,
                                thinking: isBotThinking
                            }
                        };
                        conversations.push(newConversation);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            res.send("EVENT_RECEIVED");
    
        } catch (error) {
            let entry = (req.body["entry"])[0];
            let changes = (entry["changes"])[0];
            let value = changes["value"];
            let messageObject = value["messages"];
            if (typeof messageObject !== "undefined") {
                let messages = messageObject[0];
                let cellphone = messages["from"];
                await sendMessageToWhatsApp(cellphone, "Ops, Lo siento! No puedo responderte actualmente, intentalo más tarde.");
            }
            next(error);
        } finally {
            isProcessing = false;
        }
    }
    
    async function sendMessageToWhatsApp(phoneNumber: string, message: string) {
    
        const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/${ID_CELL}/messages`;
    
        const payload = MessageText(message, phoneNumber)
        const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json", Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN_CLOUD_API_WSP}` };
    
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, payload, { headers: headers });
            console.log(`Message sent to ${phoneNumber}: ${message}`);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error(`Error sending message to ${phoneNumber}: ${error?.message}`);
            throw error;
        }
    
    }
    
    function MessageText(textResponse: any, cellPhone: any) {
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "to": cellPhone,
            "text": {
                "preview_url": true,
                "body": textResponse
            },
            "type": "text"
        });
        return data;
    }
    
    
    module.exports = {
        verifyToken,
        receiveMessage
    };

// OpenAIService.TS
    import axios from "axios";
    import { TOKEN_OPEN_AI } from "../utils/secrets";
    
    export async function getAnswerFromOpenAI(text: string) {
    
      const start = Date.now();
      const apiKey = TOKEN_OPEN_AI;
      const url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
      };
    
      const data = {
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        "messages": [
          {
            "role": "user",
            "content": text
          }
        ],
        "temperature": 0.4
      };
    
      const response = await axios.post(url, data, { headers: headers })
      const end = Date.now();
      const elapsed = end - start;
      // const answer = response?.data.choices[0].message.content.trim() ?? "Ops, Lo siento! No puedo responderte actualmente, intentalo más tarde.";
      console.log(`Response time was ${elapsed}ms, sending delayed message`);
    
    
      if (response) {
        return response;
      } else {
        console.log('ocurrio un error con OpenAI');
        return null;
      }
    
    }








// INDEX.TS
    import express, { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
    import dotenv from "dotenv";
    import cors from "cors";
    import mainRouter from "./routes/main";
    import { PORT } from './utils/secrets';
    
    dotenv.config();
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cors());
    
    app.use('/api/v1', mainRouter);
    
    
    app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500).json({ title: 'Api Error', message: 'Error Interno del Servidor', err });
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```

Comment: Hola como estas verificando que no se repita el webhook de respuesta al cliente

Comment: Si, eso lo verifico a traves del ID pero aun asi no me explico porque los mensajes se repiten. Es decir, entiendo que es porque Whatsapp no recibe un estado 200, pero se supone que se lo envio cada vez que se responde el mensaje. Ademàs que cada vez que se recibe o envia un mensaje recibo en los estado del webhook un estado fallido con código 131047, que dice que no se puede enviar un mensaje distinto después de las 24hrs

Comment: Y se supone que ese codigo solo se recibe si intentas enviar un mensaje antes de que él usuario sea el que comience la conversación. Lo cual no sucede porque es decir, el usuario comienza la conversación y el bot contesta con un mensaje del tipo texto.

Comment: Yo creo que de alli viene el problema porque si por cada mensaje que envio y recibo whatsapp me envia un estado fallido es como si no hubiera tenido respuesta lo que puede hacer que se me esten repitiendo los mensajes. Lo malo es que aunque pregunte en facebook no contestan